# Referencing Outlets from subclass to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, iboutlet

So I'm relatively new to swift and would really appreciate some help!

I've got this subclass setup where I have connected my UIView

```
class SwipeCell: FoldingCell {         
     @IBOutlet weak var card: UIView!
}
```

I want to be able to reference this UIView in my main ViewController.The ViewController though already has a UITableView connected to it so whenever I connect another Outlet I get the error for repeated connections.

So far I've tried doing this in my ViewController but getting the error 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var swipeCell = SwipeCell()

     func resetCard() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
             self.swipeCell.card.center = self.view.center
             self.swipeCell.card.alpha = 1
        })

    }

}
```

This function is then referenced inside a Button which will hopefully reset the card onto the when it gets swiped off. I've got all the swiping animations working but struggling with the resetting because of the outlet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome in the Stackoveflow. Sometimes it might be helpful to describe what the program should do or what should it look like. In your example I don't see mentioned. Also it is known, that any UITableView setup is done using UITableViewDataSource methods like -cellForRow. Do you use ones?

Comment: The error you've described - `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'` is just trying to indicate that your `card` outlet hasn't been correctly connected to anything. 

Here's guidance from Apple regarding this - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html - search for 'Create Outlets for UI Elements'.

Comment: basically the program is setup so that you can swipe a card (UIView) off the screen. What i'm trying to get working now is resetting the card once it has been swiped off the screen. I'm pretty sure that my outlet is set up correctly. Its just how reference it in the viewController. I'm really new to swift and I dont think my first attempt was the correct way of going about this. I do have a UITableViewDataSource in my viewController but it has no cellForRow. The cellForRow is in my UITabBarDelegate